# How to send large json data to api using php curl?

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl

**Post Large amount of data from server A to B**.

I am using Laravel apis. I need to post large amount of data (>8mb) using PHP Curl from server a to Laravel API. If data size is less than 5mb, it is working fine but when data amount is large, is shows empty post data on Laravel side.

Please check my code.

PHP CURL (Server A):

```
$payload=array();
$payload['a']='123';
$payload['name']='i';
$payload['i']=$base64;
$payload['b']='abc';

$request_headers = array(
                "Content-Type:application/json",
                'Content-length:' . strlen($payload)
            );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 104857640);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      
      $res=curl_exec($ch);
```

**$base64** is php variable, it contains string of 7mb(dynamic value).

Laravel Controller (POST method api):

```
$a=$req->a;
$b=$req->b;
$name=$req->name;
$i=$req->i;

        if($a=='' || $b=='')
        {
           
            $arr["req"]=  $request->all();
            $data = $request->getContent();
            $arr["data"] = $data;
            $arr["headers"]=$request->headers->all();
            return response()->json($arr); 
        }
```

> $request->all()

Returns empty

> $request->getContent();

Returns base64 sting only 1.1mb.

I tried also **'expect:'** into curl header, but no luck.

PHP limitation also increased:

```
   php_value max_execution_time 300
   php_value max_input_time 600
   php_value memory_limit 400M
   php_value post_max_size 400M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 400M
```

Comment: Are you sure that the configuration values are actually taken into account ? A quick `phpinfo()` on a test page could allow you to ensure the problem does not come from the configuration.

Comment: Yes, configuration is taken by account. 
Even, I also tried ini_set function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a php limitation.

Run

```
ini_get('post_max_size');
```

If it's less that the needed, then run

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '32');
```

Same for files.

```
ini_get('upload_max_filesize ');
```

Then

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize ', '30M');
```

Some servers don't allow ini_set(), in that case you will have to modify though php.ini or the hosting settings.

***** Note that post size needs to be always greater than upload size.

Comment: PHP limitation also increased.

Comment: My bad I read too quickly.

Still, does the config respect the values? Have you tried ini_get on them to see if they're correct?